# Changing values in a column according to the values from another column in the same dataframe (python)

Tags: python, dataframe, function, lambda, apply

This is a part from a dataframe with data of patients in clinic.
As you can see, I have several rows for each caseid in my dataframe.
Also, I have only one row for each caseid which indecating if the patient came earlier/later/on time - with a value of '1'.

I want that instead that will be a value '1' only in one row for each patient,
that I will insert the number of caseid of the patient in the relevant column ('ealier_count'/'later_count'/'on_time_count'), and that it will be shown in all of his rows.

For example I will use the image attached- as we can see, caseid came earlier and its indecated in one of his rows with value 1 in cloumn 'earlier_count'.
I want that instead I will see in the column 'earlier_count' his number of case id (361474) for all of his rows (from index 203918 until index 203929) in that column.
How can I do it?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdvBj.jpg)

I tried to start with converting only the value 1 to the caseid number but I didn't succeed.

merged_2['earlier_count'].apply(lambda x: x if x == '0' else merged_2.loc[merged_2['caseid'] == x, 'caseid'].values[0])

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Add the data sample as *text*, not as a picture. E.g. try `df.to_dict()`, or something like `df.loc[203918:203937].to_dict()` in this case, and post in a block between triple backticks (```). Show both input *and* expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following for each column:-

```
df['col_name'] = np.where(df.col_name == 1,df.case_id,df.col_name)
```

Comment: thank you, I did this code but I got the number of the index instead of the number of the caseid of the patient.

Comment: Just change df.index to df.case_id .My bad I didn't read that attachment carefully.

Comment: Thank you!! it worked now with this code : qflow['earlier_count'] = np.where(qflow['earlier_count'] == 1, qflow['caseid'], qflow['earlier_count'])

qflow['earlier_count'] = qflow.groupby('caseid')['earlier_count'].transform('max')